# WP - displaying posts in a category easier way to code

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

Hi I would like to find an easier way to code my block below. I am doing if statements on categories based on post type, then spitting out posts including titles/featured image /content. Wondering if there is an easier way with a for loop - looping through an array or similar?

Currently it is:

```
        if(in_category('hoses-posts')){
            $args = array( 'post_type' => 'hoses_posts' , 'category_name' => 'hoses-posts' , 'order' => 'ASC', 'posts_per_page'  => 30);
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();?>
            <?php get_template_part('templates/loop-product');?>
            <?php
            endwhile;

        } elseif(in_category('hoses-isobaric')){

            $args = array( 'post_type' => 'hoses_posts' , 'category_name' => 'hoses-isobaric' , 'order' => 'ASC','posts_per_page'  => 30);
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();?>
            <?php get_template_part('templates/loop-product');?>
            <?php
            endwhile;

        } elseif(in_category('hoses-braid')){

            $args = array( 'post_type' => 'hoses_posts' , 'category_name' => 'hoses-braid' , 'order' => 'ASC','posts_per_page'  => 30);
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();?>
            <?php get_template_part('templates/loop-product');?>
            <?php
            endwhile;

        } elseif(in_category('hoses-spiral')){

            $args = array( 'post_type' => 'hoses_posts' , 'category_name' => 'hoses-spiral' , 'order' => 'ASC','posts_per_page'  => 30);
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();?>
            <?php get_template_part('templates/loop-product');?>
            <?php
            endwhile;

        } elseif(in_category('hoses-speciality')){
          and so on....
        }
```

Update:

I have grabbed this piece of code from here:https://gist.github.com/DevinWalker/6fb2783c05b46a2ba251. unsure if this is correct way to go about it ?

```
              $post_type = 'hoses-posts';

                // Get all the taxonomies for this post type
                $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( array( 'post_type' => $post_type ) );                   
                foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) :                    
                    // Gets every "category" (term) in this taxonomy to get the respective posts
                    $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );                     
                    foreach( $terms as $term ) : ?>
                    <?php
                        $args = array('post_type' => $post_type, 'order' => 'ASC','posts_per_page'  => -1 ,'tax_query' => array(array('taxonomy' => $taxonomy,'field' => 'slug','terms' => $term->slug, ) ) );
                        $posts = new WP_Query($args);

                        if( $posts->have_posts() ): ?> 

                          <?php echo $term->name; ?>

                        <?php while( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post(); ?>

                            <?php get_template_part('templates/loop-product');?>                                       

                        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

                    <?php endforeach;

                endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try optimizing your code in this way,

```
<?php
function get_template( $category_name ) {
  $args = array( 'post_type' => 'hoses_posts' , 'category_name' => $category_name , 'order' => 'ASC', 'posts_per_page'  => 30);
  $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
  while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    get_template_part('templates/loop-product');
  endwhile;   
}

if ( in_category('hoses-posts') ) {
    get_template( 'hoses-posts' );
} elseif ( in_category('hoses-isobaric') ) {
    get_template( 'hoses-isobaric' );
} elseif ( in_category('hoses-braid') ) {
    get_template( 'hoses-braid' );
} elseif ( in_category('hoses-spiral') ) {
    get_template( 'hoses-spiral' );
} elseif ( in_category('hoses-speciality') ) {
  and so on....
}
```

Comment: Hi thx for this. Unfortunately I can't seem to get this working. error log says "29-Sep-2016 01:34:53 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare get_template()"

Comment: Hi there I have just changed function name to get_template_hoses(..) and works. Perhaps conflicting with existing WP function https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template

Comment: ah I just use that name of function similar with dummy name, you're free to chose at your convenience..

Comment: Hi there wondering if there is a way to loop through post types? I have other post types 'couplings_posts', 'technical_posts' etc so I don't have to keep redeclaring multiple functions? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

My solution

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'hoses_posts' , 
    'category_name' => in_category('hoses-posts'), 
    'order' => 'ASC', 
    'posts_per_page'  => 30
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    get_template_part('templates/loop-product');
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Dont forget close WP_query by function wp_reset_postdata()